Handling Blazor Route Parameter on MainLayout?
Question about routing in the context of a .NET 8 Blazor Webassembly application.
I want to achieve the following URL's:

/{store-slug}/products/{product-slug}
/{store-slug}/checkout
/{store-slug}/login
...

problem statement
I understand I can easily do this by adding [Parameter] properties within the specific page. But this is going to be big project and I want to avoid dealing with fetching the store on each & every page.
Thought process
Ideally my {store-slug} logic can all be handled from within my MainLayout.razor.
This would allow me to simplify my productdetail.razor page for example:
@page "/products/{product-detail}" instead of @page "/{store-slug}/products/{product-slug}".
What I'm trying to achieve is very similar to ASP.NET MVC AREAS. Anyone can guide me in the right direction? Adding the [Parameter] to my MainLayout.razor is not working. I've checked in with ChatGPT but nothing usefull is coming out, it's hinting towards modifying my app.razor routing, but nothing that really makes sense.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Where does 'store-slug' come from?Do you want to add   'store-slug' to the page of a module or the whole project?

I don't think this is possible.


(1) Create a BasePage with [Parameter] string Store-Slug {get;set;} for your slug.
(2) Make sure your parameter gets to cascading parameter or some kind of service that keeps the status of store-slug.
(3) Inherit the BasePage
(4) Use the cascading param in the MainLayout.


Works like a charm, thanks a lot! Totally forgot about the @inherits possibility. Cheers!
